# Connect to MySql Docker-Container from Intellij's Database Tool

Tags: mysql, docker, intellij-idea

I have created a docker MySQL container like this

`docker run  --detach   --name internal-mysql -p 6604:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=user_pass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=internal -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pass mysql`

The container is running fine

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES e802cd30e6a2        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 seconds ago      Up 41 seconds       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6604->3306/tcp   internal-mysql`

Within the container I have checked the user host and it looks fine doesn't it?

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| user             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

but when I try to connect to that DB from IntelliJ or my Spring-Boot app I always receive the same error

[image]

Of course I tried to google and figured out that for some cases it helped to figure out the container ip via `docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" internal-mysql`

which resulted in 172.17.0.2

I have tried to connect via `jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/internal-mysql`

I have tried it with JDBC MYSQL Driver 8.0.21 and 5.1 with both no success.

Any idea please?

Comment: you published `6604` port to host so connect to it from intellij.

Comment: Post that as an answer please that you get the score ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you published `3306` port of mysql container on port `6604` of your host - you should use `6604` port when trying to connect to your mysql docker container from the host.